# Import JSON with objects as nested to Elastic Search

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nested

i've log with thousands records of aggregated data in JSON:

```
{
  "count": 25,
  "domain": "domain.tld",
  "geoips": {
    "AU": 5,
    "NZ": 20
  },
  "ips": {
    "1.2.3.4": 5,
    "1.2.3.5": 1,
    "1.2.3.6": 1,
    "1.2.3.7": 1,
    "1.2.3.8": 1,
    "1.2.3.9": 9,
    "1.2.3.10": 7
  },
  "subdomains": {
    "a.domain.tld": 1,
    "b.domain.tld": 1,
    "c.domain.tld": 1,
    "domain.tld": 22
  },
  "tld": "tld",
  "types": {
    "1": 3,
    "43": 22
  }
}
```

and i have mapping on ES:

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "count": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "domain": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "ips": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "val": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "geoips": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "val": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "subdomains": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "val": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "tld": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "types": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "val": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there any simple way how import these lines to ES as nested objects ? If i use a bulk insert without modification, the ES will modify mapping by adding a new field for each IP/subdomain/GeoIP instead add it as simple key/val object.

Or only one way is regenerate JSON to key/val nested fields ?

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is already very good but the data doesn't fit it since the `nested` data type expects an array of objects, not a single object. So you'll need to transform your nested objects into array of key-value pairs like so:

```
  ...
  "ips": [
    {
      "key": "1.2.3.4",
      "val": 5
    },
    {
      "key": "1.2.3.5",
      "val": 1
    },
    ...
  ],
  "subdomains": [
    {
      "key": "a.domain.tld",
      "val": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "b.domain.tld",
      "val": 1
    },
    ...
  ]
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but what i’m try find is any other simplest way instead of full transform origin JSON, because i have many GBs of these JSONs :( 

If there is no other way, i will transform it :(

Comment: Given your data, the mapping cannot possibly look like the above b/c if you were to ingest any new document, the generated mapping would look like this: https://prnt.sc/vxsba6 So yeah, you can either drop the index, set the mapping from above again and insert those GBs or you could use the `_reindex` API. Here's a guide: https://www.lewuathe.com/how-to-reindex-elasticsearch.html

Comment: I will convert a origin JSON files to required format, there is no other way :( Your sample is not possible use, because after load few thousands lines i got error with maximum 1000 fields limit (each value will create a new field if not exists). So, its look that only one way is change structure of JSON.

Comment: Yup, the 1000 is another side effect of that. That setting is increasable to higher values but you don't need to do that when you're reindexing afresh.